# Spree Commerce Product Data Import Tools

Tags: e-commerce, spree

I need to import about 300 products with different variants into a Spree Commerce rails application.  Does any have import tools to recommend for this job?  Or do I need to build it.

Comment: Hi I just created a data load utility, and loaded 17K products.  It is written in Groovy not Ruby.  It took about 3 weeks to get it all worked out, but I was only working half time.

Comment: also check out https://github.com/joshmcarthur/spree-import-products

Answer (score 2):

Right now you have the 'Import products' extension, maybe it's useful for you.

http://www.spreecommerce.com/extensions/103-import-products

Alf.